# How to start this activity use adb shell am start -D -d pg/xx.The activity name is Main$Activity

Tags: android, debugging, shared-libraries

I want to debug android's so file. I use  start an Activity: am start [-D] [-W]  to start activitey.
the applicationg package name is com.dualboot.apps.springzen  . the main activity is com.dualboot.apps.springzen.Main$Activity . i use command
'adb shell am start com.dualboot.apps.springzen/com.dualboot.springzen.Main$Actinity'

it's  not exist

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.dualboot.apps.springzen/com.dualboot.springzen.Main }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.dualboot.apps.springzen/com.dualboot.springzen.Main} does not exist.
```

how to start this activity

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling a component you need to include the component `-n` option tag.

Use this:

```
adb shell am start -n com.dualboot.apps.springzen/.MainActivity
```

if you actually have the `$` in your class name (I doubt it) which usually refers to an inner class then you need to use:

```
adb shell am start -n com.dualboot.apps.springzen/.Main\$Activity
```